# How to force Local Task Menu to display on specific pages

Tags: routes

I’ve made a tabbed display out of my Local Task Menu as imaged.

Some of the extra buttons are ‘pages’ as made with ‘pages manager’  .  Here you can assign the page to the Local Menu; when doing so by this method the created page also shows with these user tabs.

However a couple of pages ( one created by the Nodequeue and the other a Custom Module made by myself ) ; with these I’ve assigned to MENU_LOCAL_TASK  in hook_menu_alter   .  And although they show up in the menu when clicked on they no longer have the Local Task Menu.  Does anyone know a way I can force these pages to show it ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this be engineering a fix with ( https://www.drupal.org/project/local_tasks_blocks )

There is a patch here at https://www.drupal.org/node/2141653 for 'Fixed path for displaying tabs'  which sounds like the same issue I had .  However the patch didn't work for me.

Checking the value of $tasks['#primary'] ; I concluded that if I could keep this array for a session then I could use the Local Tasks Menu on all the pages I wished while the User is logged in.  Ie something like

```
if (empty($tasks['#primary'])) {

// 1.  Check the cookies if we have one then use that
if (isset($_SESSION['usertasks']['primary'])) {

$tasks_primary = $_SESSION['usertasks']['primary'];
$tasks['#primary'] = $tasks_primary;
}
else {
$usertasks = &$_SESSION['usertasks'];
// well need to create a new instance of this array so we don't    effect it for the page we're on
$tasks_primary = $tasks['#primary'];
$usertasks['primary'] = $tasks_primary;
  }
}
```

My next step is to make a patch for this if anyone else may find it of use.